# Get woocommerce category by name and assign to product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hello i been searching for a while now but i cant get this to work, i cant get the category by name, and also i cant asign it to a product programatically

```
$product = new WC_Product(4);
write_log($product->get_title());

// Gets term object from Tree in the database. 
$category = get_term_by( 'name', 'bolsas', 'product_cat' );
echo "Cat: ".$category->name;

wp_set_object_terms($product->id, $cat->term_id, 'product_cat');
```

Im running this on functions.php file and reloading the page, i also have a function to log in console for debugging, but its getting me nowhere.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$tag = '5'; // Wrong. This will add the tag with the *name* '5'.
$tag = 5; // Wrong. This will also add the tag with the name '5'.
$tag = array( '5' ); // Wrong. Again, this will be interpreted as a term name rather than an id.

$tag = array( 5 ); // Correct. This will add the tag with the id 5.
wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $tag, $taxonomy );
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped, because in theme functions.php woocommerce taxonomies where not yet loaded, si it had to be hooked on init.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27111/get-term-by-not-working-when-in-functions-php